# More intelligent automatic formatting

Tags: formatting, filetype-tex

I use vim to edit latex files and the automatic formatting option (`formatoptions+=a`) works very well, since you can enter text anywhere in the paragraph and vim will reformat the entire paragraph.

The problem is that when I edit a set of lines containing commands, like this

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Apple
  \item Banana
\end{enumerate}
```

vim treats the text as though it were a paragraph, and will reformat to this

```
\begin{enumerate} \item Apple \item Pear \end{enumerate}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically reformat prose only. A solution specific to latex might just ignore lines beginning with `\` but perhaps there is a smart general solution involving some vim settings.